# Windows Batch For Loop - Variable not setting

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

EDIT: It appears I had a stray `GOTO :EOF` at the end of an `ECHO` statement, and it will actually GOTO :EOF... d'oh! Thanks for responses. I think the bug is squashed now.

---

I have a script where I want to roll through a text document comparing if the files match.

Script here:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=1* delims=\" %%a in (NoMatchA.txt) DO (
        set "flag="
        for /f "tokens=1* delims=\" %%i in (NoMatchB.txt) do (
                IF "%%b"=="%%j" SET flag=1
        )
        IF DEFINED flag ECHO FLAG DEFINED
        IF NOT DEFINED flag ECHO FLAG NOT DEFINED
)
endlocal
```

made up Input from `NoMatchA.txt` and `NoMatchB.txt` made up example:

```
1234567890 \TEMP\ANIMALS\DOGS\FILE1.pdf
0987654321 \TEMP\TREES\I hate willows.docx
1122334455 \TEMP\LINUX ISOS\linustarvolds.iso
1029384756 \COVID\CANSUCk\MYBALLS\prettyflowers.jpg

1231509876 \USERS\HOMERSIMPSON\Doh.wav
1234567890 \TEMP\ANIMALS\DOGS\FILE1.pdf
0987654321 \TEMP\TREES\I hate willows.docx
1029383321 \COVID\CANSUCk\MYBALLS\prettyflowers.jpg
```

You get the picture. If I ECHO the `IF "%%b"=="%%j" SET flag=1` I can clearly see in instances that they are equal, yet `flag` still shows as not defined.

So basically if the file names match I want to process that data a certain way.

Comment: Maybe make `if` case insensitive like `IF /I "%%b"=="%%j" SET flag=1`?

Comment: Do your file or folder names have a `%` in them, or `!`. If you can't provide us an actual data set that fails to work, I don't know how we are supposed to help. As it stands, what you posted above works fine unless there are special characters in the file and folder names. The problem is in the contents of the files as you already pointed out, so provide the content that is problematic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

•| **Edit:** This will prevent the remaining lines from going through the 2nd `for` loop when the `flag` has been set, and the line identities have already occurred.

As the flag has already been set, the loop does not need to continue.

If there are few lines, nothing changes, but if you have many lines, this can make a big difference in the total time process.

When adding the `goto :skip`, you goto exit the 2nd `for`cloop immediately, avoiding repetitive processing for each line, because you already been found the same string/line match.

```bat
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

cd /d "%~dp0" && if NOT exist NoMatchB.txt call :^) 

for /f "tokens=1*" %%a in (NoMatchA.txt) DO (

     SET "FLAG="
     for /f "tokens=1*" %%i in (NoMatchB.txt)do if NOT defined flag (
         IF /i "%%~b"=="%%~j" ( 
             SET "flag=1"
             goto :skip
            )   
         )

     :skip
     ECHO\value  FLAG==!flag!
     IF DEFINED flag (ECHO\echoed FLAG==1) ELSE ECHO\echoed FLAG==Undefined?

     ECHO\
    )

endlocal && goto :EOF
```

This is some that I prefer deal using with some different method.

You start the first loop by removing a variable, from there, it will only exist when some value is equal to `"%%~b"` and `"%%~j"`.

After that point, there is no need to compare any values ​​within `"%%~b"` and `"%%~j"` in your  2nd loop.

**<sub>Use `if /i` and `~` ("`%%~b`") to remove double quotes from the string and compare the two variables in the loop with "double quotes"</sub>**

```bat
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

cd /d "%~dp0" && if NOT exist NoMatchB.txt call :^) 

for /f "tokens=1*" %%a in (NoMatchA.txt) DO (

     SET "FLAG="
     for /f "tokens=1*" %%i in (NoMatchB.txt)do if NOT defined flag (
         IF /i "%%~b"=="%%~j" SET "flag=1"
        )

     ECHO\value  FLAG==!flag!
     IF DEFINED flag (ECHO\echoed FLAG==1) ELSE ECHO\echoed FLAG==Undefined?

     ECHO\
    )

endlocal && goto :EOF

:^)
>NoMatchA.txt (
     echo;1231509876 \USERS\HOMERSIMPSON\Doh.wav
     echo;1234567890 \TEMP\ANIMALS\DOGS\FILE1.pdf
     echo;0987654321 \TEMP\TREES\I hate willows.docx
     echo;1029383321 \COVID\CANSUCk\MYBALLS\prettyflowers.jpg
     echo;9999999999 \COVID\CANSUCk\MYBALLS\FlowersOnly.jpg
    ) && (
>NoMatchB.txt (
    echo;1234567890 \TEMP\ANIMALS\DOGS\FILE1.pdf
    echo;0987654321 \TEMP\TREES\I hate willows.docx
    echo;1122334455 \TEMP\LINUX ISOS\linustarvolds.iso
    echo;1029384756 \COVID\CANSUCk\MYBALLS\prettyflowers.jpg
    echo;9999999999 \COVID\CANSUCk\MYBALLS\OnlyFlowers.jpg
    ) ) && exit /b
```

If I'm wrong or not, not sure, but this work for me, see the results:

```bat
value  FLAG==
echoed FLAG==Undefined?

value  FLAG==1
echoed FLAG==1

value  FLAG==1
echoed FLAG==1

value  FLAG==1
echoed FLAG==1

value  FLAG==
echoed FLAG==Undefined?
```

1. In all loops pass in your 1st loop, you remove the variable `flag`:

```bat
set "flag="
```

2. In first `for` loop remove the variable `flag`, in your 2nd `for`, you first check if your flag is not yet defined, if true, compare your variable `%%~b` and then `set` your `flag` variable to value `1`:

```bat
 if not defined flag IF /i "%%~b"=="%%~j" SET "flag=1"
```

3. **`Refer edit`** after setting its variable flag, because `%%~b == %%~j`, there is no need to continue comparing with the remaining lines of the file in this 2nd loop, then just use a `goto :label` to exit the loop immediately and continue the main loop.

```bat
    IF /i "%%~b"=="%%~j" (
       SET "flag=1"
       Goto :skip
       )   
  )

 :skip
```

---

Comment: Ah yes, I'll give that a try. Thank you very much. Should be more efficient.

Comment: This will prevents unnecessary `if` in 2nd `for` loop after flag are set., But, you also can add `goto :skip` in 2nd loop.  See edit: